# Can I convert a knob to deadbolt - in a steel door?

Tags: doors

I have a fantastic commercial grade steel door.  It has a regular knob (a very good one) and 2-3/4" spacing.

Folks would rather have a deadbolt there instead of the knob.  **The door swings in.**

Will a deadbolt physically "bolt up" in a doorknob position without drilling, cutting or welding?

It would presumably have a pull handle on the door inside.  How do I attach this?  The steel door doesn't weigh a ton so it must be hollow, and I'm worried if I through-bolt it, I'll crush the door.

Comment: If I am not mistaken door knob openings and dead bolt openings are identical (interchangeable). Attaching your handle is a different story as you said and steel doors typically are hollow - the edge is a bit different though. I have not been in any plants that make steel doors (only fiberglass doors) so I am not aware of intricacies in how steel doors are manufactured. I assume the outer areas have a scaffolding structure like a frame around for exactly the reasons you mention. When you take the knob off - you might be able to take a look inside and verify this.

Comment: strong magnets can attach the handle. or epoxy,.